# indy 9 returning a 404 error when POSTing to https .aspx page

Tags: delphi, https, indy

I'm using the Indy 9 `TIdHTTP` component with `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket` to POST to an aspx page (https://www.thedogs.co.nz/catch-the-action/results.aspx) to emulate what happens in a browser to view a specific months race results.
The code below *should* download results for November 2015.

First, I GET the URL then parse it to extract values for `__VIEWSTATE` (theVS), `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` (theVSG) and `__EVENTVALIDATION` (theEV).

Then I do this:

```
with HTTP do
begin
  AllowCookies := True;
  ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication := False;
  ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 0;
  Request.ContentLength := -1;
  Request.ContentRangeEnd := 0;
  Request.ContentRangeStart := 0;
  Request.Accept := 'text/html, */*';
  Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;  rv:42.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0';
  Request.ContentType:= 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  Request.ContentEncoding := 'utf-8';
  HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];
end;
```

Sl is a `TStringList`, M is a `TMemoryStream`.

```
Sl.Add('__VIEWSTATE="' + theVS + '"&');
Sl.Add('__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR="' + theVSG + '"&');
Sl.Add('__EVENTVALIDATION="' + theEV + '"&');
Sl.Add( 'txtCurrentDate="1/12/2015%2012:00:00%20a.m."&');
Sl.Add( 'txtAction="prevMonth"');

Url := 'https://www.thedogs.co.nz/catch-the-action/results.aspx';
HTTP.Post( Url, SL, M );
showmessage( 'sent' );
AssignFile( F, '.\downloaded\theresults' );
Rewrite( F );
M.Position := 0;
SL.LoadFromStream(M);

for X := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do
  WriteLn( F, SL[ X ] );

CloseFile( F );
```

All I get back however is the exception

> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Any help most appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You are not formatting the `TStringList` content correctly. You need to get rid of the `"` and `&` characters, and DO NOT url-encode the values. `Post()` handles all of that internally when formatting the actual HTTP request.

You are also setting some `Request` properties you do not need to set, or are setting to invalid values.

After you `Get()` the page to retreive cookies and ViewState data, on the subsequent requests, you are not setting the `Request.Referer` property to the same URL.  Any time a link or a form on one page is used to access another page, the `Referer` header needs to be set accordingly.  Some servers validate that to make sure requests are coming from the right place.

Try this:

```
with HTTP do
begin
  AllowCookies := True;
  ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication := False;
  ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 0;
  Request.Accept := 'text/html, */*';
  Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;  rv:42.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0';
  HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];
end;

Url := 'https://www.thedogs.co.nz/catch-the-action/results.aspx';

... := HTTP.Get(Url, ...);
// parse HTML as needed...

Sl.Add('__VIEWSTATE=' + theVS);
Sl.Add('__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=' + theVSG);
Sl.Add('__EVENTVALIDATION=' + theEV);
Sl.Add( 'txtCurrentDate=1/12/2015 12:00:00 a.m.');
Sl.Add( 'txtAction=prevMonth');

HTTP.Request.Referer := Url;

HTTP.Post( Url, SL, M );

M.Position := 0;
SL.LoadFromStream(M);
SL.SaveToFile( '.\downloaded\theresults' );
// or simply: M.SaveToFile( '.\downloaded\theresults' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Remy. I've made the suggested changes but still getting a HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found error .

Comment: @ChazF: are you using a proxy server?

Comment: @ChazF: The code I showed works fine for me in the latest version of Indy 10.  I get a `200 OK` reply from the server, and the expected HTML for November 2015. Indy 9 is old, maybe you are encountering a bug that has long been fixed.

Comment: @Remy - your persistent efforts are most appreciated.... I'll download and install Indy 10. Best regards.

Comment: Not having much luck installing Indy10... I've even gone through the process of deleting EVERYTHING INDY-RELATED from the HDD, plus removed the Indy9 packages from Delphi and starting from scratch, but I just cannot install the package dclIndyProtocols50.bpl - itt just comes up with a entry point error. I've heard of other people achieving it, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the actual error message? And are you really using Delphi 5?

Comment: Hi Remy - yes, I am using Delphi 5. It appears that there is a problem compiling the Indy 10 modules. When I initially ran the batch file FULLD50 I could see that there appeared to be a large number of messages. So, I opened IndySystem50.dpk in Delphi and compiled it - got a large number of hints:

Comment: @Remy...Continued...[Hint] Package 'IndySystem50' does not use or export 'IdGlobal.TIdTextEncodingBase.GetByteCount', [Hint] Package 'IndySystem50' does not use or export 'IdGlobal.TIdTextEncodingBase.GetBytes', [Hint] Package 'IndySystem50' does not use or export 'IdWinsock2.IN6_SET_ADDR_LOOPBACK' There are 115 fints in total, some refer to idGlobal and most refer to idWinsock2.

Comment: @Remy...Continued...There are 115 fints in total, some refer to idGlobal and most refer to idWinsock2.                                                                                              IndyCore50.dpk compiles without any hints or warnings.indyProtocols50.dpk produces3 warnings and 12 hints             dclIndyCore50 produces a Fatal Error:                                                                                                       dclIndyProtocol350.dpk produces 190 warnings, 3 errors and severl hints

Comment: @ChazF: I don't need to see **hints** about unused code. What are the actual **errors** that are preventing you from installing?

Comment: @Remy: when I complle IndyCore50.dpk I get [Fatal Error] IdDsnPropEdBindingVCL.pas(80): Internal error: U1158 Line 80 is 'IdSocketHandle;' - compiling dclIndyCore50.dpk gives the same error - compiling dclIndyProtocols50 gives the error: [Fatal Error] IdDsnSASLListEditorFormVCL.pas(62): Internal error: U1158 ( Line 62 is ' Classes, IdSASLCollection;' ----------------- I'm running under Windows 10.

Comment: @ChazF: Those are compiler failures, not Indy code errors. If you search online, you will find references of how to deal with error U1158.

Answer (score 0):

A big "thank you" to everybody for your able assistance. The problem turned out to be a Windows 'thing'. Some years back my hard drive failed and in the process of replacing it I upgraded to Win 7. About a year later I decided to move up to Windows 8. HATED IT!! Asap, upgraded to 8.1, and finally a few months ago, 10.

Wondering if the above had any bearing on my Delphi problem I thought I take a look at just what was actually on drive C: - I noticed a folder called something like ~windows, or windows.old or some such. Inside it was a complete windows fileset, however also inside it was another complete WINDOWS folder.
Long story short - booted to a DOS prompt and deleted all of the files in the folder using the command 'del *.* /S/F/Q' then deleted all the folders and I am now very happy to report that at last I have a Delphi + Indy10 that is working wonderfully!